# how to redirect all files in a subfolder to root directory with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory, friendly-url

i have a directory like `www.example.com/comments/a/word1.html` I removed `comments/a/` section and `.html` with htaccess from link. Under the `a` folder i have lots of files like word1.html, word2.html , word3.html,  and i want to redirect all of these files like this:
`www.example.com/word1`
`www.example.com/word2`
`www.example.com/word3`

I am using this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?comments/a/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/a%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/? /comments/a/$1.html [END]
```

but i got the error "404 page not found, The resource requested could not be found on this server!". What can i do in this situation? Is there any way to redirect `www.example.com/comments/a/word1.html`  word2-3-4 etc. also to `www.example.com/word1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of my researchs i found a solution like this :

```
##Rewrite non /comments/a/ links internally start##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/a/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.?]+)$/?$ comments/a/$1.html [L,NC]
##Rewrite non /comments/a/ links internally end##
```

This code works like a charm for me.